# SharePoint Server 2019 on-premises managed paths

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, 2019, managed-path

I need some explanations on how managed paths are working in SharePoint Server 2019.

I have a web application that has a site collection. For example: the URL of the site collection `http://HQ`. I'm planning to create many site collections underneath the root HQ (up to 60 site collections or even more).

According to Microsoft documentation, no more than 20 managed paths should be used in a web application to avoid performance issues.

My question:

Can I create my own managed path "Departments" (Wildcard inclusion) underneath the root HQ and then create all site collections underneath the Departments? Does the 20 managed path limit apply to this scenario?

the Url would be something like:

```
http://hq/departments/hr
http://hq/departments/finance
http://hq/departments/marketing,,etc.
```

I want to make sure that I'm following the best practices for site collections.

Thank you.